# asynch call in onSubmit

Tags: javascript

I am new to `asynch`, I am trying to use `asynch` with `firebase`, once the token is set I would like to fire the actions, `fetchEvents`, and `navigate`

```
async setToken() {
    const fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
    return fcmToken;
}

onSubmit(e) {
    const {
        navigation: { navigate },
        credentials: { year, group, student },
        fetchEvents
    } = this.props;

    AsyncStorage.setItem(
        "loggedIn",
        JSON.stringify(this.props.credentials)
    );

    const token = this.setToken();

    if (token) {
        fetchEvents(student || group);
        navigate("Month");
    }
}
```

If I inspect `token` in my debugger it is a promise:

```
_40: 0
_55: null
_65: 0
_72: null
```

How can I get `asynch` to work with my function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `async` function returns Promise. Simple as that.

```
async setToken() {
    const fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
    // Now if you console.log() the fcmToken will be string

    return fcmToken;
}

console.log(setToken()) 
// This will be promise and inside will be fcmToken, 
// because anything you return from async function will be wrapped in Promise.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` the function call as well:

```js
async onSubmit(e) {    //  <-- add "async" here
    const {
        navigation: { navigate },
        credentials: { year, group, student },
        fetchEvents
    } = this.props;

    // for that matter, this here being called "AsyncStorage" suggests 
    // that you *might* want to await this too.
    AsyncStorage.setItem(
        "loggedIn",
        JSON.stringify(this.props.credentials)
    );

    const token = await this.setToken();  //  <-- add "await" here

    if (token) {
        fetchEvents(student || group);
        navigate("Month");
    }
}
```